# Which are all additive maps from $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ to $\mathbb{F}_2^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups

Let's just consider the additive groups of the vector spaces $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

What are the maps $\mathbb{F}_2^m\to\mathbb{F}_2^n$ that respect this additive structure? Are they the maps that are linear maps between $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ and $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ as vector spaces, and are they only those? That is, can they all be expressed via matrices and matrix-multiplication?

Comment: A map $T$ between two $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces is a linear transformation if and only if $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(ax) = aT(x)$ for all vectors $x,y$ and all scalars $a$. But the only scalars are $a=0$, in which case the second formula says $T(0) = 0$ (which follows from additivity), and $a=1$, in which case the second formula says $T(x)=T(x)$. In either case, homogeneity follows from additivity. Thus, a map between two $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector spaces is linear if and only if it is additive. (In fact, this is true for any $\mathbb{F}_p$ and for $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: One can also approach this from the perspective of (additive) group homomorphisms. Fix a basis $B$ for $\Bbb F_2^m$; then any homomorphism out of $\Bbb F_2^m$ is determined completely by the images of the elements of $B$. Those images can be chosen freely from among the elements of order $1$ or $2$ in the codomain—in this case, every element of $\Bbb F_2^n$ is a possibility.